# Display time in ListLinePlot x axis

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I am new user of mathematica. I want to plot a csv file look like this:

```
2020-03-13 12:18:03,7.65,4.95,6.5,297.9,6.7,74.5,35.05,2.45,39.7,31.35,39.7,22.9
2020-03-13 12:28:09,9.25,5.25,6.15,30.95,5.6,47.25,19.5,2.8,49.85,34.55,34.55,29.45
2020-03-13 12:28:15,9.7,6.9,5.05,34.15,4.7,40.45,26.2,2.85,47.7,31.8,32.55,35.6
```

I searched some questions, and I learn ListLinePlot, then I plot the graph using:

```
data = Import["D:\\R1.csv"];

ListLinePlot[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]], data[[All, 3]], 
  data[[All, 4]], data[[All, 5]], data[[All, 6]], data[[All, 7]], 
  data[[All, 8]], data[[All, 9]], data[[All, 10]], data[[All, 11]], 
  data[[All, 12]]}, ImageSize -> Full, PlotLegends -> Range[1, 12]]
```

However, the x axis only display numbers but not time. How to make the x axis to display time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two key concepts you need for this are

- the [`DateObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) primitive, which allows you to turn a string with a date (which is what the first column of your data gets imported as) into a formal date object that can be recognized by Mathematica; and

  > [image]
- the [`DateListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html) command, which takes lists whose abscissa is a date object and produces suitable plots from them.

For your data, you can then start by transforming the first row

```
transformedData = Transpose[Join[
   {DateObject /@ data[[All, 1]]},
   Transpose[data[[All, 2 ;;]]]
   ]]
```

(notice the use of the [`/@`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) syntax to encode a `Map` command) and then putting that into the plotting command:

```
DateListPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[
   transformedData[[All, {1, j + 1}]]
   , {j, 1, 12}]]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

There's fancier ways to do this which are more in line with the Mathematica way to do things, but these are not wrong and they should be relatively easy to understand for a newcomer.

Comment: what does ;; mean? (Transpose[data[[All, 2 ;;]]])

Comment: It's a shorthand for [`Span`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) -- it means the range from position 2 to the end of the list.